# Circular cropping of image in konvajs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, crop, konvajs, konva

I wanted to show circular cropped image in my canvas and I'm using konvajs.
Is there any way to do it in konva itself or is there any workarounds with JS/CSS?

This is the code I use for loading the image.

```
var src = 'https://konvajs.github.io/assets/yoda.jpg';
    Konva.Image.fromURL(src, function(yoda) {
        console.log(yoda);
        yoda.setAttrs({
            x: 10,
            y: 10,
            width: 180,
            height: 180
        });
        group.add(yoda);
        layer.batchDraw();
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is a way offered by konva itself. To do this, you have to define a **clipping region** either for a konva layer or a group. This clipping region can be as simple as a rectangle or something more advanced like a circle.

The shape is set using the `clipFunc` property of a layer or group. This property expects a function which contains a set of drawing operations to define your actual shape. So in case of a circle, you would utilize the `context.arc()` operation.

Here's an example:

```js
var src = 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300';

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer({
  clipFunc: function(ctx) {
    ctx.arc(130, 140, 70, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  }
});
stage.add(layer);

Konva.Image.fromURL('https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300', function(theDog) {
  theDog.setAttrs({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1,
  });
  layer.add(theDog);
  layer.batchDraw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@7.2.5/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I added image in a group and clipped it, and, added it to another group.